# Migrate data with Entity Framework migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How would you migrate data with EF Migrations if you first have to read data to transform it in a column?

```
public partial class MigrateContextData : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // How could I access existing data to migrate?
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

I would have thought at first "SELECT" with migrationBuilder... but I don't get row results back.

I solved this problem this way, but it is of course not a clean solution:

```
        private void UpdateDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EventContext>())
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Check if database migration is needed");
                var migrationsToDo = context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
                if (migrationsToDo.Any())
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Migration is needed");
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                    _logger.LogInformation("Migration is finished");

                    // Is a MigrateContextData needed?
                    if (migrationsToDo.Any(x => x.Contains("20191127102444_MigrateContextData", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)))
                    {
                        // Workaround to migrate/transform data 
                        MigrateContextDataImplementationAfterMigration(context);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```